# It just stopped working - google-app-script google-drive-api createFile

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a google app script that suddenly quit working today.  It is crashing on the ***parentFolder.createFile(pdf).setName(theFileName+".pdf");***

I am not showing all of the code, it has been working form a couple of years, and then suddenly it is throwing an error...  sorry not sure how to capture errors, kinda new at this.

```
var myHTML =   "<... a bunch of html stuff ...>;

var blob = Utilities.newBlob(myHTML, MimeType.HTML);
var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf").setName(theFileName+".pdf"); // theFileName set above
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(theFolderId);  // theFolderId is set above
parentFolder.createFile(pdf).setName(theFileName+".pdf");  // theFileName is set above
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what might be going on?  I am assuming it may be related to the email I received "***Drive API requires updates to your code before Sep 13, 2021***", and google has started some testing that may have inadvertent results for their customers??

***Here is another example that I used when I first started this project, and the "Exception" it raised.  Today!!***

**Exception: Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed. (line 7, file "Code")**

```
function htmlToPDF() {

  var html = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, "text/html", "text.html");
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");

  DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf");  // this is line 7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI... ISSUE is not with my code - it actually a google issue and has been reported to their "Issue tracker" [issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640)

The parent thread... https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196100674

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way, you may save some lines in your code. I'm not saying that this didn't work before, but this is a workaround that solves the problem now.

#### Example:

```js
function htmlToPDF() {
  // Case one 
  var myHTML = "<h1>... a bunch of html stuff ...</h1>";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(myHTML, "application/pdf", {theFileName} + ".pdf");
  var theFolderId = '{FOLDER ID}';
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(theFolderId);
  parentFolder.createFile(blob);

  // Case two
  var html = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, "application/pdf", "text.pdf");
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);

}
```

---

For capturing errors you could use a [try...catch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```js
try {
  nonExistentFunction();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  // expected output: ReferenceError: nonExistentFunction is not defined
  // Note - error messages will vary depending on browser
}
```

Comment: I was creating a HTML from an email thread and creating a HTML. From the HTML, I was creating a PDF. It was working well. But, it is throwing the error "Exception: Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed" for the last few days.  This is the code //var tempFile = DriveApp.createFile("temp.html", html, "text/html");
      //folder.createFile(tempFile.getAs("application/pdf")).setName(subject + ".pdf");
      //tempFile.setTrashed(true);

Comment: Thank you for the help with trapping errors...  will try that...

FYI...  ISSUE is not with my code - it actually a google issue and has been reported to their "Issue tracker" https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640