# Exception: Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed - from yesterday

Tags: html, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was saving my emails as PDF. It was working well. It stopped working for the last few days with the error

Exception: Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed

It is also reported by someone here :

[It just stopped working - google-app-script google-drive-api createFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748892/it-just-stopped-working-google-app-script-google-drive-api-createfile)

```
function saveGmailAsPDF() {

  var gmailLabels  = "TESTING";
  var driveFolder  = "TEST2";

  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:" + gmailLabels, 0, 5);

  if (threads.length > 0) {

    /* Google Drive folder where the Files would be saved */
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveFolder);
    var folder = folders.hasNext() ?
        folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder);

    /* Gmail Label that contains the queue */
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels) ?
        GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels) : GmailApp.createLabel(driveFolder);

    for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {

      //threads[t].removeLabel(label);
      var msgs = threads[t].getMessages();

      var html = "";
      var attachments = [];

      var subject = threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject();

      /* Append all the threads in a message in an HTML document */
      for (var m=0; m<msgs.length; m++) {

        var msg = msgs[m];

        html += "From: " + msg.getFrom() + "<br />";
        html += "To: " + msg.getTo() + "<br />";
        html += "Date: " + msg.getDate() + "<br />";
        html += "Subject: " + msg.getSubject() + "<br />";
        html += "<hr />";
        html += msg.getBody().replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");
        html += "<hr />";

        var atts = msg.getAttachments();
        for (var a=0; a<atts.length; a++) {
          attachments.push(atts[a]);
        }
      }

      /* Save the attachment files and create links in the document's footer */
      if (attachments.length > 0) {
        var footer = "<strong>Attachments:</strong><ul>";
        for (var z=0; z<attachments.length; z++) {
          var file = folder.createFile(attachments[z]);
          footer += "<li><a href='" + file.getUrl() + "'>" + file.getName() + "</a></li>";
        }
        html += footer + "</ul>";
      }

      /* Convert the Email Thread into a PDF File */


      //The PDF craeted is damaged by the below code
      //var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, "application/pdf").setName("mail" + ".pdf");
      //var theFolderId = '{FOLDER ID}';
      //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(theFolderId);
      //folder.createFile(blob);

      // PDF is damaged by the below code
      //var html = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
      //var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, "application/pdf", "text.pdf");
      //DriveApp.createFile(blob);


      //the below code was working well. 
      var tempFile = DriveApp.createFile("temp.html", html, "text/html");
      //the bellow line is giving the error for the last few days
      //Error : Exception: Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed
      folder.createFile(tempFile.getAs("application/pdf")).setName(subject + ".pdf");
      tempFile.setTrashed(true);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an ongoing bug. It seems that it has already been reported to Google Issue Tracker. Go to [the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/196100674) and click the white star (☆) at the top-left (just left of the issue ID) to increase its priority.